# Why do I get a warning message from separate function

Tags: r

When I use the `separate` function to separate the data frame into name to first name and last name :
ERROR shows like this:

> Warning message:
> Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 10 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].

Code:

```
library(tidyr)
id<-c(1:10)
name<-c("john","ravi kumar","vikas regmi","rakesh barjatia","mandy cloy","clay cook","praveen regmi","michael armstrong", "jose hoe", "saurabh kumar")
job_title <-c("CA", "chief consultant", "vice-consultant", "CTO", "CMO", "CFO","CEO","people analyst","data analyst","HR")

employee<-data.frame(id,name,job_title)
print(employee)
separate(employee,name,into=c('first_name','last_name'),sep='')
```

I use this function and expect the separation of data between first name and last name.

Comment: I'm guessing it is due to `sep=''` when you need `sep=' '`

Answer (score 2):

The issue that raised in OP's situation is due to using `sep=''` instead of `sep=' '` (already adressed by @user20650 in the comments, Many thanks!).

Here is how to use `separate` function:
Using `separate()` in columns where not all the two values that you want to separate in, are existent like row1, then `separate()` by default will fill these missing values from the right side with `NA`.

**We could control this with the `fill` argument:**
See `?separate()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

employee %>% 
  separate(name, into=c("first_name", "last_name"), sep=" ", fill="right")
```

```
   id first_name last_name        job_title
1   1       john      <NA>               CA
2   2       ravi     kumar chief consultant
3   3      vikas     regmi  vice-consultant
4   4     rakesh  barjatia              CTO
5   5      mandy      cloy              CMO
6   6       clay      cook              CFO
7   7    praveen     regmi              CEO
8   8    michael armstrong   people analyst
9   9       jose       hoe     data analyst
10 10    saurabh     kumar               HR
```